# Pass data into middleware - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I need to do a verify, if the user has made the request.
Can I pass the requested variable into middleware?

**route.php**

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'isRichiedenteOrIncaricato'], function () {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routes per gestire l'elaborazione delle richieste
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    Route::get('/elaborazione_richieste/{richiesta}', 'ElaborazioneRichiesteController@show');

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routes per gestire i commenti nella pagina elaborazione richieste
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    Route::post('/elaborazione_richieste/{richiesta}/comments','CommentsController@store');

});
```

**isRichiedenteOrIncaricato.php**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (\Auth::user() && \Auth::user()->id == 1 || \Auth::user() && \Auth::user()->id == 2) {
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        $request->session()->flash('message.level', 'danger');
        $request->session()->flash('message.content', 'Non puoi visualizzare questa pagina, devi essere il richiedente o l\'incaricato!');
        return redirect('/home');
    }


}
```

Comment: What you mean by "requested variable"?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin variable inside the route, like {richiesta}...

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `route()` method of request object:

```
$request->route('richiesta')
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! Very easy and usefull!